# Maven: Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor and peer not authenticated errors despite the settings.xml having repositories configured with HTTPS

Tags: java, maven, https, maven-3

I have `Maven 3.0.5` with `Java 8` setup (that's for particular project and stack versions won't be revised).

I'm aware of `Apache`'s new decision to force all the Maven repositories to only use HTTPS, otherwise Maven clients won't be able to speak to the repository servers.

It seems like I have configured all necessary settings in `~/.m2/settings.xml` but for some reason, when I any build phase (say `mvn clean`), Maven defaults to `HTTP` and doesn't care about `settings.xml` - it still attempts to download references/dependencies with HTTP protocol.

Example of my `settings.xml`
(For simplicity, I removed project specific things and left only problem-related stuff):

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                    https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>central</id>
    <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
  </repository>

  <repository>
    <id>central</id>
    <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

and here is what I'm getting when I do `mvn archetype:generate`, just to test the behaviour of Maven (the problem is persistent for any other command that tries to reach servers out):

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects... 

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.3/maven-install-plugin-2.3.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.3

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/2.7/maven-deploy-plugin-2.7.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.7

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/3.0/maven-site-plugin-3.0.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:jar:3.0

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/1.3/maven-antrun-plugin-1.3.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:1.3

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/2.2-beta-5/maven-assembly-plugin-2.2-beta-5.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:2.2-beta-5

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.1/maven-dependency-plugin-2.1.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.1

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-release-plugin/2.0/maven-release-plugin-2.0.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:jar:2.0

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml

[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required.

[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required.

[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced.

Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required.

[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced.

Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required.
```

What shall I do? as you see, it still uses HTTP, and I, correspondingly, get HTTP 501.

Comment: First upgrade to most recent version of Maven 3.6.3. Other option is to use a mirrorOf configuration in your settings.xml and redirect all access via the correct url in particular if you are in a corporate environment I strongly recommend to use a repository manager which would handle all  this kind of things...

Comment: As I said, that's for particular stack of the legacy project, so versions can't be revised. Can you give me an example of how to use that `mirrorOf` configuration and/or repository manager for this very case?

Comment: Reinstall maven to > 3.6 (latest versions of Maven)

Comment: Read the questions carefully, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two problems:

**Problem 1:**
`[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for .. (whatever plugin name)` warnings during almost any build phase, which says that (important>) the retrieval of *plugin descriptors or its dependencies* (which means *plugins*, and not the *project dependencies*!) is not going successful.

Here, Maven attempts to communicate with the end-point machine (repository) via HTTP, **despite the fact**(!), that I have customized my configuration `.m2\settings.xml` file and all the repository definition entries are with HTTPS, respectively, seems like Maven should be trying everything via HTTPS ..but no, it uses HTTP for plugins, and any HTTP communication with Maven repositories is [forbidden since the 15th of January, 2020](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041287334).

The way I resolved this is to define and configure `<profiles/>` and `<pluginRepositories/>` as [@carlspring suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60093279/1553537), but I had to elaborate and expand that answer a bit.

So, here is my ready working `settings.xml` example: (note, that just to be safe, I provided alternative repositories in both - profiles and repositories)

```
<settings
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"                                                                                                                                     $    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
        https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>ssl-profile</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>

            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>central-1</id>
                    <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>central-2</id>
                    <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>

        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>central1</id>
                <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>central2</id>
                <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profiles>
</settings>
```

After this was resolved, and finally Maven attempted to connect to all the repositories via **HTTPS**, I then had another,

**Problem 2:**
`peer not authenticated` followed by `Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required.`

This was a bit tricky, but the way of solving this is to play with truststore `cacerts` file.

First, check whether you have truststore file `cacerts` and whether it's empty. it must **NOT** be empty and this is very important.

It seems like, in the `OpenJDK 11` and in some other builds for Windows/Linux systems, `cacerts` file is either missing or present, but empty; however, according to my observation, it was present in `Oracle JDK` builds.

- On `Windows` builds, it should be under `%JAVA_HOME%\lib\security\`;
- On Linux builds, it may vary (depending on Linux distribution and your setup), but in my case, it was under `/etc/ssl/certs` (and I think that's Linux's certificates folder, not particularly Java's one).

If you see, that `cacerts` file is either absent or empty (simply check the file size, it should be larger than few bits), you can either:

- Simply copy-paste existing `cacerts` file from some other JDK/JRE build;
- [Generate](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3503/6nf1il6er/index.html) a `cacerts` truststore file and add certificate(s) to it. In this case, you will need to add as many certificates as you need, so, maybe it's easier to go with just a copy-paste variant.

I hope this helps.

Comment: If you upgrade to a newer Maven, you won't have to do all this wizardry yourself, as it's configured to use the correct `cacerts`. I would strongly recommend upgrading to Maven 3.6.3. In addition, if you're using JDK 1.8, you should upgrade to the latest one, as there were many SSL changes, particularly around CA certs and such. If I recall correctly, you need to be using a version >= `jdk8u211`.

Comment: 1. Yeah, I know that, but I think I wrote around 3 times above, that in this situation, stack is given as is, and it's a legacy project.. I can't do anything here. Question starts with `"versions won't/can't be revised".` :)

2. Maven has nothing to do with `cacerts` (at least in this case), as maven uses `Java` to run, and that's why you have to configure `JAVA_HOME`, which it looks for when it runs. Java should have a proper `cacerts` file inside the build.

Comment: I'm sure there might me a lot of people/projects which might find this useful.. especially after major change in Apache Maven (regarding dropping HTTP). So, I think it's worth to keep this solution here.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, it seems to be working for dependencies, but not for plugins. You need to define a `<profile>` that is `activeByDefault` and contains a `<pluginRepositories/>` section for both snapshot and releases.

Maven has two types of repositories:

- For dependencies
- For plugins

The `<mirrorOf>` section only handles dependency repositories.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this a bit more please? where that should be defined and how? is it ok if the plugin repository will be only one or two at most? just a bit more info, please.
Also, I suspect that reason you deduced that it works for dependencies, is that it gives a `WARNING` that artifact descriptor can't be downloaded.. am I right?

Comment: I added this into `settings.xml`
<profile>
    <id>activeByDefault</id>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</profile>

Still the same..

Comment: This is exactly what I meant, except it's not the `<id/>` that needs to be active, but the profile, like this `<activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>`. I see you've managed to get it to work...?

Comment: See my answer please :) but thanks, your suggestion helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to go the following path:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">

  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>central</name>
      <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>

</settings>
```

This will redirect all request via the above URL. If you have a repository manager inside of your corporate environment it's better to use this one and let the repo manager handle the https stuff.

Also an upgrade of Maven to most recent version 3.6.3 and I supose you are not using the most recent versions of plugins which I strongly recommend to upgrade there had been a lot of improvements.

Comment: > Downloading: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5

and > [WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): peer not authenticated

Comment: So, as you see it indeed goes to HTTPS, but why do I have some problem.. :( I'm so tired already..

Comment: The only new thing I have is `[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2): peer not authenticated`after I setup profiles and https repositories.. any more help please?

Comment: As I mentioned network/proxy/firewall issue... I can't help here cause that's within your corporate environment...

Comment: No, it was not about proxy/firewall. See my answer please.