# Java SSL handshake_failure error in Netbeans using Maven Plugin

Tags: java, maven, ssl, netbeans, netbeans-plugins

I'm trying to compile a Maven project in Netbeans, which, during the build process, is trying to download files from a remote server. The process fails with handshake_failure. I've tried to add multiple options to the Maven plug-in in Netbeans to no avail. I tried:

```
-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true   
-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true   
-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true  
-Dhttps.protocols="TLSv1"
```

Oracle's explanation of the debug output isn't of much help. I used the "-Djavax.net.debug=all" option to get the build debug output below:

```
cmd /c "\"\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.0.2\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.bat\" -Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\\Users\\Max\\AppData\\Roaming\\NetBeans\\8.0.2\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar 
-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1 -Djavax.net.debug=all clean install\""
Scanning for projects...

trustStore is: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\security\cacerts
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Equifax Secure Global eBusiness CA-1, O=Equifax Secure Inc., C=US
  Issuer:  CN=Equifax Secure Global eBusiness CA-1, O=Equifax Secure Inc., C=US
  ...
  ...

trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
trustStore is: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\security\cacerts
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore

adding as trusted cert:
  ...
  ...

trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Downloading: http://www.dukascopy.com/client/jforexlib/publicrepo/com/dukascopy/dds2/DDS2-jClient-JForex/3.6.19/DDS2-jClient-JForex-3.6.19.pom
pool-1-thread-1, setSoTimeout(1800000) called
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
pool-1-thread-1, setSoTimeout(1800000) called
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1594509174 bytes = { 243, 62, 231, 63, 139, 40, 217, 136, 4, 46, 2, 173, 244, 20, 202, 106, 28, 255, 51, 135, 163, 250, 254, 217, 85, 133, 187, 126 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 151
0000: 01 00 00 93 03 01 5F 0A   47 76 F3 3E E7 3F 8B 28  ......_.Gv.>.?.(
0010: D9 88 04 2E 02 AD F4 14   CA 6A 1C FF 33 87 A3 FA  .........j..3...
0020: FE D9 55 85 BB 7E 00 00   2C C0 0A C0 14 00 35 C0  ..U.....,.....5.
0030: 05 C0 0F 00 39 00 38 C0   09 C0 13 00 2F C0 04 C0  ....9.8...../...
0040: 0E 00 33 00 32 C0 08 C0   12 00 0A C0 03 C0 0D 00  ..3.2...........
0050: 16 00 13 00 FF 01 00 00   3E 00 0A 00 34 00 32 00  ........>...4.2.
0060: 17 00 01 00 03 00 13 00   15 00 06 00 07 00 09 00  ................
0070: 0A 00 18 00 0B 00 0C 00   19 00 0D 00 0E 00 0F 00  ................
0080: 10 00 11 00 02 00 12 00   04 00 05 00 14 00 08 00  ................
0090: 16 00 0B 00 02 01 00                               .......
pool-1-thread-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 151
[Raw write]: length = 156
0000: 16 03 01 00 97 01 00 00   93 03 01 5F 0A 47 76 F3  ..........._.Gv.
0010: 3E E7 3F 8B 28 D9 88 04   2E 02 AD F4 14 CA 6A 1C  >.?.(.........j.
0020: FF 33 87 A3 FA FE D9 55   85 BB 7E 00 00 2C C0 0A  .3.....U.....,..
0030: C0 14 00 35 C0 05 C0 0F   00 39 00 38 C0 09 C0 13  ...5.....9.8....
0040: 00 2F C0 04 C0 0E 00 33   00 32 C0 08 C0 12 00 0A  ./.....3.2......
0050: C0 03 C0 0D 00 16 00 13   00 FF 01 00 00 3E 00 0A  .............>..
0060: 00 34 00 32 00 17 00 01   00 03 00 13 00 15 00 06  .4.2............
0070: 00 07 00 09 00 0A 00 18   00 0B 00 0C 00 19 00 0D  ................
0080: 00 0E 00 0F 00 10 00 11   00 02 00 12 00 04 00 05  ................
0090: 00 14 00 08 00 16 00 0B   00 02 01 00              ............
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 15 03 01 00 02                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 02 28                                              .(
pool-1-thread-1, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
pool-1-thread-1, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
pool-1-thread-1, called closeSocket()
pool-1-thread-1, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
pool-1-thread-1, called close()
pool-1-thread-1, called closeInternal(true)
pool-1-thread-1, called close()
pool-1-thread-1, called closeInternal(true)
pool-1-thread-1, called close()
pool-1-thread-1, called closeInternal(true)

trustStore is: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\security\cacerts
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
adding as trusted cert:
  ...
  ...
  
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/dukascopy/dds2/DDS2-jClient-JForex/3.6.19/DDS2-jClient-JForex-3.6.19.pom

trustStore is: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\security\cacerts
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=Equifax Secure Global eBusiness CA-1, O=Equifax Secure Inc., C=US
  Issuer:  CN=Equifax Secure Global eBusiness CA-1, O=Equifax Secure Inc., C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0xc3517
  Valid from Mon Jun 21 00:00:00 EDT 1999 until Mon Jun 22 00:00:00 EDT 2020

adding as trusted cert:
  ...
  ...

trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Downloading: http://www.dukascopy.com/client/jforexlib/publicrepo/com/dukascopy/api/JForex-API/2.13.90/JForex-API-2.13.90.pom
pool-3-thread-1, setSoTimeout(1800000) called
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
pool-3-thread-1, setSoTimeout(1800000) called
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1594509175 bytes = { 202, 169, 233, 171, 134, 58, 229, 244, 130, 132, 57, 64, 32, 52, 14, 201, 13, 210, 98, 83, 222, 207, 99, 23, 103, 7, 206, 164 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 151
0000: 01 00 00 93 03 01 5F 0A   47 77 CA A9 E9 AB 86 3A  ......_.Gw.....:
0010: E5 F4 82 84 39 40 20 34   0E C9 0D D2 62 53 DE CF  ....9@ 4....bS..
0020: 63 17 67 07 CE A4 00 00   2C C0 0A C0 14 00 35 C0  c.g.....,.....5.
0030: 05 C0 0F 00 39 00 38 C0   09 C0 13 00 2F C0 04 C0  ....9.8...../...
0040: 0E 00 33 00 32 C0 08 C0   12 00 0A C0 03 C0 0D 00  ..3.2...........
0050: 16 00 13 00 FF 01 00 00   3E 00 0A 00 34 00 32 00  ........>...4.2.
0060: 17 00 01 00 03 00 13 00   15 00 06 00 07 00 09 00  ................
0070: 0A 00 18 00 0B 00 0C 00   19 00 0D 00 0E 00 0F 00  ................
0080: 10 00 11 00 02 00 12 00   04 00 05 00 14 00 08 00  ................
0090: 16 00 0B 00 02 01 00                               .......
pool-3-thread-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 151
[Raw write]: length = 156
0000: 16 03 01 00 97 01 00 00   93 03 01 5F 0A 47 77 CA  ..........._.Gw.
0010: A9 E9 AB 86 3A E5 F4 82   84 39 40 20 34 0E C9 0D  ....:....9@ 4...
0020: D2 62 53 DE CF 63 17 67   07 CE A4 00 00 2C C0 0A  .bS..c.g.....,..
0030: C0 14 00 35 C0 05 C0 0F   00 39 00 38 C0 09 C0 13  ...5.....9.8....
0040: 00 2F C0 04 C0 0E 00 33   00 32 C0 08 C0 12 00 0A  ./.....3.2......
0050: C0 03 C0 0D 00 16 00 13   00 FF 01 00 00 3E 00 0A  .............>..
0060: 00 34 00 32 00 17 00 01   00 03 00 13 00 15 00 06  .4.2............
0070: 00 07 00 09 00 0A 00 18   00 0B 00 0C 00 19 00 0D  ................
0080: 00 0E 00 0F 00 10 00 11   00 02 00 12 00 04 00 05  ................
0090: 00 14 00 08 00 16 00 0B   00 02 01 00              ............
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 15 03 01 00 02                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 02 28                                              .(
pool-3-thread-1, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
pool-3-thread-1, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
pool-3-thread-1, called closeSocket()
pool-3-thread-1, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
pool-3-thread-1, called close()
pool-3-thread-1, called closeInternal(true)
pool-3-thread-1, called close()
pool-3-thread-1, called closeInternal(true)
pool-3-thread-1, called close()
pool-3-thread-1, called closeInternal(true)

trustStore is: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\security\cacerts
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
adding as trusted cert:
  ...
  ...
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/dukascopy/api/JForex-API/2.13.90/JForex-API-2.13.90.pom

------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 4.643s
Finished at: Sat Jul 11 19:12:56 EDT 2020
Final Memory: 7M/155M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Finalizer, called close()
Finalizer, called closeInternal(true)
Finalizer, called close()
Finalizer, called closeInternal(true)
Failed to execute goal on project JForex-3-SDK: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.dukascopy.dds2:JForex-3-SDK:jar:3.6.19: Failed to collect dependencies for [com.dukascopy.dds2:DDS2-jClient-JForex:jar:3.6.19 (compile), com.dukascopy.api:JForex-API:jar:sources:2.13.90 (compile)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.dukascopy.dds2:DDS2-jClient-JForex:jar:3.6.19: Could not transfer artifact com.dukascopy.dds2:DDS2-jClient-JForex:pom:3.6.19 from/to dc_public (http://www.dukascopy.com/client/jforexlib/publicrepo/): Received fatal alert: handshake_failure -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

I also tried the Unlimited strength jurisdiction option as suggested in this [Reply to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40291972/ssl-handshake-failure-with-java-version-1-7-0-79) but that didn't help either.
Any Ideas?

Comment: Try to force the download from https url of repository (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60092920/cant-make-maven-use-https-despite-the-settings-xml-configuration-where-i-have-r) for more info), If you need a specific https repository download the certificate and add to your cacerts (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325263/how-to-import-a-cer-certificate-into-a-java-keystore) for more info)

Comment: Thanks. I still get the handshake_failure error. I applied the additional profile settings in C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\java\maven\conf\settings.xml and I already had the certificate imported.

Comment: TLSv1 is pretty old, try to remove or use 1.2/3, in your log there's Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org, you need to use https, so see how to change repository URL, or update your maven plugin, do you add the certificate to the java library that you use to run this command?

Comment: I tried 1, 1.2 and 1.3 (please see new log here [link](https://pastebin.com/636USR1a))

Comment: I was using Netbeans 8.0.2. After installing and using Netbeans 12.0, all issues were resolved without having to change any settings.